# SQL Server Join - With INFO_SCHEMA information

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the first table:

```
select COLUMN_NAME 
from Emerald_Data.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
where TABLE_NAME = N'tbl_Client_List_Pricing'
```

[image]

Don't mind the numbering in the `Column_Name`. I was doing this while testing because I need the order to remain as they are in the table. Not by ASC, DESC.

Anyhow, I don't know how to use the row numbers on the left that the system provides to JOIN another table without a condition.

Here is Table 2:

[image]

You can see that the left row numbers are my linking value but I don't know how to use that system index value as a condition in my JOIN.

Or if there is another way to join these two tables without a condition while keeping the Table 1 information in it's correct position and not affecting it by ORDER would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

-Chase

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess you are looking for `row_number`. Use `row_number` to order result of two queries then join by matching order nums. Your query would be something like

```
with query_1 as (
    select COLUMN_NAME
        , rn = row_number() over (order by cast(left(COLUMN_NAME, 3) as int)) 
    from Emerald_Data.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
    where TABLE_NAME = N'tbl_Client_List_Pricing' 
)
, query_2 as (
    select
        *, rn = row_number() over (order by (select null))
    from
        Table_2
)

select
    *
from
    query_1 q1
    join query_2 q2 on q1.rn = q2.rn
```

Comment: I was going to suggest `ROW_NUMBER()` as well, just this question is a bit chaotic given that there isn't a true way to guarantee the order of the columns. Clever usage of `order by (select null)` since OP didn't want to order by anything. Clever ;)

Comment: Thanks a ton.  It spit an error where it was cast as int.  I just modified it to cast as nvarchar(10) instead and it worked beautifully.

And yes.  As Brien had mentioned the order by (select null) was exactly what I was missing as well and I will make sure to remember that.  Very cool.

Answer (score 0):

```
select COLUMN_NAME from Emerald_Data.INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
inner join with Table_2 on Num=cast(LEFT(COLUMN_NAME,CHARINDEX('-', COLUMN_NAME)) AS int)
where TABLE_NAME = N'tbl_Client_List_Pricing'
```

Comment: try to add some more details while you are answering any questions. The code may work as expected but its good if you can explain that too. It will help other users in future.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `sys.all_columns` object which could able to state the index for your desired column & `JOIN` them with table2

```
SELECT * 
FROM sys.all_columns c
INNER JOIN Table2 t ON t.Num = c.column_id
WHERE OBJECT_NAME(object_id) = 'tbl_Client_List_Pricing'
```